# Module federation The remte app can not read the config File when the Shell call it (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, micro-frontend, angular-module-federation

I have Problem with Angular Mfe Module federation,
I have Host app and remote app, each of them in separate Workspace.
when I run the remote app alone it work and it can read the config File, but when the host app call the remote app, the remote app has no access to the (remote) config file and it can not call the URl for the API. what it the best way that I can Access the Config file, who has all the API URLs.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfJmE.png)

Update:
let me ask another way,
2 Angular Apps Shell App `localhost:4000` and Remote App `loaclhost:4001` using Mfe (Module federation) each of them in Workspace (each of them has it own `angular.json`) and each of them has under assets a `config.json`.
in the remote app the `config.json` has all the Api urls, when i load the remote app as single app it works fine and it reads the `config.json`.
but when i run the Shell app and call the remote app from it,the `config.json` of the remote app is not readable and the URLs come empty. i do not know why.
Any one has the Idea how can the remote app read it own `config.json` when i call it from the shell app.
thank.

thanks